# Adding cascade deletion in a rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a schema.rb with:

```
add_foreign_key "dog", "trees"
```

I would like it to say:

```
add_foreign_key "dog", "trees", on_delete: :cascade
```

I am thinking of a migration like this:

```
class ModifyTreeRefFromDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column  ...
  end
end
```

Comment: ...did you try running it, then looking at the db-structure to see if it worked?

Comment: The '...' needs to be filled in with some code i believe. @TarynEast

Comment: Did you see `dependent: :destroy` attribute?

Comment: yes... with the code you've already written :) I've put it in an answer to make it clear for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drop it and add it again (it's an index, no information is lost).

```
class ModifyTreeRefFromDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_foreign_key "dog", "trees"
    add_foreign_key "dog", "trees", on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

Note: this seems to be a good reference for foreign keys in rails and includes exactly the on_delete code you tried: [Foreign Keys in Rails 4.2](https://richonrails.com/articles/foreign-keys-in-rails-4-2)

Comment: The schema.rb highly recommends not changing it directly, rather using migrations to do so.

Comment: It gave: -- drop_foreign_key("dog", "trees")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Comment: undefined method `drop_foreign_key'

Comment: remove as opposed to drop worked, and it worked overall, thank you

Comment: Yeah, I always mix up the rails vs sql words.. drop/remove :)